# How to associate file extension (not file type) for a particular application?

Tags: filesystem, configuration, file-association

I use [taskcoach](http://taskcoach.org/) to create a list of my tasks.

The data I entered was saved, say, in tasks.tsk on my Desktop. Internally, this is an XML file of specific structure.

Now whenever I open it, it opens in my text editor, like any other XML.

I've tried changing extension to .task and .my_tasks, but associated program is the still the editor.

After googling and reading forums, I've right-clicked the file, and in `Properties` -> `Open With` chose TaskCoach.

The file opens in TaskCoach, but any other .XML file gets opened with TaskCoach too!

Q: How do I make ubuntu open .task files in TaskCoach while preserving association .xml -> editor?

Comment: Just a suggestion, could you re-associate .xml with gedit and see if it helps.

Comment: @Amey tried that. Before I introduced the new mime-type the association was the same, regardless of .xml or .task or .tsk extension.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rename the file you have as `_anything_.task` (where `_anything_` is something suitably descriptive.)

First you need to create an XML file with the extension information in it. (If you wish, copy the text below into a new text file and save it as `task.xml`.)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mime-info xmlns='http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info'>
<mime-type type="application/taskcouch">
<comment>TaskCoach File</comment>
<comment xml:lang="bg">Taskcoach</comment>
    <comment xml:lang="cs">Taskcoach</comment>
    <comment xml:lang="de">Taskcoach</comment>
    <comment xml:lang="es">Taskcoach</comment>
    <comment xml:lang="eu">Taskcoach</comment>
    <comment xml:lang="hu">Taskcoach</comment>
    <comment xml:lang="it">Taskcoach</comment>
    <comment xml:lang="ko">Taskcoach</comment>
    <comment xml:lang="nb">Taskcoach</comment>
    <comment xml:lang="nl">Taskcoach</comment>
    <comment xml:lang="nn">Taskcoach</comment>
    <comment xml:lang="sv">Taskcoach</comment>
    <comment xml:lang="uk">Taskcoach</comment>
    <comment xml:lang="vi">Taskcoach</comment>
<glob pattern="*.task"/>
<alias type="application/taskcoach"/>
</mime-type>
</mime-info>
```

You now need to save or copy this new file into the directory

- `~/.local/share/mime/packages` for a per-user file association or
- `/usr/share/mime/packages` for a system-wide file association.

Once that is done, run

```
update-mime-database [MIME-DIRECTORY]
```

where `[MIME-DIRECTORY]` is the previously chosen directory minus the `/packages` suffix. (Use `sudo` for the system-wide association.)

Now, open your file manager and right-click on *anything*.task and select taskcoach as the default program with the open with option in the context menu.

Job done. All `.task` files will now open with taskcoach!

Comment: NB You will need to be admin or root to cp file to /packages

Comment: I tried doing this for an application installed in my home folder and it doesn't work. I changed the task.xml file above accordingly, copied it to /usr/share/mime/packages and ran `sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime`. Tried logging out and in again to no avail.

Answer (score 4):

> The file opens in TaskCoach, but any other .XML file gets opened with TaskCoach too!

That happens because they’re all the same MIME type (`application/xml`).

If you want TaskCoach files to be treated differently from other XML files, you need to configure a new MIME type for them.

I’ve never done that before, but it looks like Gnome has pretty good documentation on how to do it: [Add a custom MIME type for all users](https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/mime-types-custom.html.en) / [individual users](https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/mime-types-custom-user.html.en).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to mess around too much manually, assoGiate is the GUI tool of your choice. See [here](https://ubuntugenius.wordpress.com/2009/11/19/create-your-own-file-types-in-ubuntu-with-assogiate/) for further information.