# How to open a file with drag to application?

Tags: unity, file-association

I use `GpsPrune` to view some gps dumps, unfortunately there is no setting to double-click and open the files in the viewer. In older versions of Ubuntu you could just drag any file to the icon of an application, how do I do that or enable that in 12.10?

Comment: It appears as thorugh the bounty period has run out. There's still a grace period left. After that the bounty will have gone to waste. So please consider accepting one of the answers below.

Comment: Not quite answering your question, but if you have a GpsPrune window open, you can drag files into it (of any type) and they will be opened. But that's a feature of the latest version of GpsPrune, which hasn't made its way into the Ubuntu repositories yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what file types GPSprune handles and which, specifically, you are interested in. So for the sake of simplicity let's just say you want to open files with the `.foo` extension in GPSprune. These files however are recognized as text files or XML files rather than GPSprune specific files. What you will have to do then is to first define a new MIME type that is specific to these files.

To do so you can either use [assoGiate](https://ubuntugenius.wordpress.com/2009/11/19/create-your-own-file-types-in-ubuntu-with-assogiate/), a GUI file type editor, or manually define the new MIME type. In this tutorial I will show how to do this manually.

Create a new text file called `foo.xml` and open it up in your favorite text editor.

Copy and paste the contents of the following text box:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mime-info xmlns="http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info">
 <mime-type type="application/foo">
  <glob pattern="*.foo"/>
  <comment>GPSprune GPS dump</comment>
  <comment xml:lang="en">GPSprune GPS dump</comment>
 </mime-type>
</mime-info>
```

Make sure to replace all instances of `.foo` with the actual extension and edit the comment/description to your wishes.

Next save the file and move it to `~/.local/share/mime/packages`. Update the mime database by typing in a terminal:

```
update-mime-database ~/.local/share/mime
```

Your `.foo` files are now recognized as a separate MIME entity. You can check whether everything worked by right clicking on a `.foo` file of your choice and looking at the file type listed under `Properties`.

Let's add an association to GPSprune now:

Open `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` in an editor of your choice. Search for the `[Default Applications]` entry or create it if it doesn't exist yet. Then add the following line under default applications:

```
[Default Applications]
application/foo=gpsprune.desktop
```

You should now be able to immediately open up your `.foo` files with GPSprune and likely also to drag and drop them on the respective launcher.

---

Sources and related Q&As:

[Add custom command in the open with dialog?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67382/add-custom-command-in-the-open-with-dialog/190927#190927)

[How can I deal with file association in different application(not in Nautilus)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40549/how-can-i-deal-with-file-association-in-different-applicationnot-in-nautilus)

[How to associate file extension (not file type) for a particular application?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55653/how-to-associate-file-extension-not-file-type-for-a-particular-application/183130#183130)

https://ubuntugenius.wordpress.com/2009/11/19/create-your-own-file-types-in-ubuntu-with-assogiate/

Comment: Nice! Unfortunately there's an error in your first XML file, but assoGiate works nicely for that.

Comment: While this is a solution to my specific problem, there doesn't seem to be any way to drag-drop to any application to see what it will do with said file. I assume this is not possible?

Comment: I am glad you found my answer useful. I found the mistake in the XML code and corrected it. The DnD operation seems to be context-sensitive and as far as I know that's hard-coded into the system. So I don't think it's possible, at least not with the Unity launcher.