# Problem associating file type to application

Tags: 12.04, default-programs, mime-type, file-type

I'm trying to make `gpxviewer` the default application to open .gpx files. The problem is that it doesn't appear in the "Open with" window neither I can add it. What I have tried:

- Using Ubuntu Tweak as recommended [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/168375/33871). It does not work for me because there is no "XML file" or "application/xml" option (.gpx files are recognized as XML files, which is correct).
- Adding "MimeType=application/xml" to the GPXViewer launcher (stored in `/usr/share/applications/gpxviewer.desktop`). Still GPXViewer does not appear as an option to open this kind of files.

So how can I make this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Option 1 (Create new Mimetype)

You can try to create a new **MimeType** *(application/gpx)* for the **gpx** files.
 Then you can set the  `gpxviewer` as default application to open them.

#### For system wide

**1)** Add the new MimeType to the gpxviewer.desktop.

- `sudo nano /usr/share/applications/gpxviewer.desktop`

Add the following line:

> MimeType=application/gpx;

[image]

Save the changes in nano with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.

**2)** Create the new MimeType.

- `sudo nano /usr/share/mime/application/gpx.xml`

Add the following to the gpx.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<mime-info xmlns='http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info'>
  <mime-type type="application/gpx">
    <comment>GPX Files</comment>
    <generic-icon name="text-html"/>
    <glob pattern="*.gpx"/>
  </mime-type>
</mime-info>
```

Save the changes in nano with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.

**NOTE:** Please change the content of the file according to your needs.

**3)** Register the Mimetype.

- `sudo xdg-mime install --novendor --mode system /usr/share/mime/application/gpx.xml`

**4)** Make the **gpxviewer** application as default to open gpx files.

- `sudo xdg-mime default gpxviewer.desktop application/gpx`

**5)** To see the changes you can Logout & Login or run the following:

- `sudo -i`
- `update-mime-database /usr/share/mime`

**Result:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

### Option 2 (Add gpxviewer to the list in application/xml)

#### For system wide

**1)** Add the *"application/xml"* MimeType to the gpxviewer.desktop.

- `sudo nano /usr/share/applications/gpxviewer.desktop`

Add the following line:

> MimeType=application/xml;

Save the changes in nano with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.

**2)** Update the database.

- `sudo -i`
- `update-desktop-database`

[image]

[image]

**NOTE**: To make **gpxviewer** default application to ope the MimeType *application/xml* ... just run:
 `xdg-mime default gpxviewer.desktop application/xml`

---

### Edit as per comment

AS [Glutanimate](https://askubuntu.com/users/81372/glutanimate) says.. you can do this not for system wide, you can create the mimetype and add the default application for users like this [Answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/262532/how-to-open-a-file-with-drag-to-application/267218#267218).

In the `~/.local/share/mime/packages` directory, update with `update-mime-database ~/.local/share/mime`.

Add an association in the `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` file,also you can **copy/create** a **.desktop** file into the `~/.local/share/applications/` directory.

---

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer. I used the first option and worked like a charm (but had to logout/login).

Comment: @Salem..Glad to help, and  yes, you are right for the first option you need the logout/login. I will edit the answer to add it. Thanks

Comment: @RomanRaguet A logout/login isn't necessarily required, you can just [update the mime database instead](http://askubuntu.com/questions/262532/how-to-open-a-file-with-drag-to-application/267218#267218).

Comment: @RomanRaguet Also, I would advise against modifying the system-wide launcher directly as it will reset on each update. It would probably be better to just add an entry to the user's `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`.

Comment: @Glutanimate...Thanks for your comments, I edited my answer. Please feel free to add more info.